# How can i make a dataframe from a list of arrays without adding brackets and double spaces?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to create a csv from a pandas dataframe with two columns, the first corresponding to an emotion and the second corresponding to the pixels of my images. The problem is that I can't get rid of the square brackets and double spaces between the numbers. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

My code:

```
#This is to prevent ellipses (...) from appearing in the csv when the number of pixels is too large
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize, edgeitems=sys.maxsize, linewidth=sys.maxsize) 

print(pixels) 
#[array([164 174  13   4 107]),array([  9 160 156 157 214]),array([139  37   7 107  50]),array([174 171 116 165  17])]

data = { "emotion": 0, "pixels": pixels[0:10] }
df_train0 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_train0.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, escapechar="\r", quotechar='"', line_terminator='\n')
```

My csv:

```
emotion,pixels
0,[164 174  13   4 107]
0,[  9 160 156 157 214]
1,[139  37   7 107  50]
1,[174 171 116 165  17]
```

How I want it to look:

```
emotion,pixels
0,164 174 13 4 107
0,9 160 156 157 214
1,139 37 7 107 50
1,174 171 116 165 17
```

Comment: As you discovered with the `set_printoptions`, the csv writer is writing a string representation of the array to the file.  If the cell elements were lists, you could omit the printoptions game, and get a list representation '[1,2,3]'.  `csv` is inherently a 2d format - rows and consistent number of columns.  You are stretching that, by somehow expecting a mix of delimiters and some sort of "sub-column".  Omitting the [] won't make loading the desired format any easier.  There have been many SO about loading csv where the list or arrays are loaded as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to string and apply some transformations:

```
df_train0.assign(pixels=df['pixels'].astype(str)
                                    .apply(lambda s: ' '.join(s[1:-1].split()))) \
         .to_csv('test.csv', index=False))
```

```
>>> %cat test.csv
emotion,pixels
0,164 174 13 4 107
0,9 160 156 157 214
1,139 37 7 107 50
1,174 171 116 165 17
```

Comment: I was having a problem with your suggestion because the values in my pixel list were numeric, but after transforming them into strings with str() everything worked perfectly! Thanks!